# Javascript call functions from element events without global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an externally loaded javascript file *(using jQuery)* I have:

```
$(function() {
    function foo() {
        console.log("bar");
    }
}
```

However in the HTML when I try and call:

```
<a onclick="foo()">Call foo</a>
```

This breaks with `Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined`.

Is it possible keeping the actual function call in the HTML *(on the `a` tag)* and have it work?

Comment: Inline event handlers can only reference global objects and that's one of the reason of many that they should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

you could attach it to the global window object:

```
$(function() {
    window.foo = function() {
        console.log("bar");
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I have lots of extenral files, and then concat them into a single file for production, there could be namespace collisions right?

Comment: yes, that's why `onclick` is generally avoided. If that's the problem, then you should use jquery to attach click listeners instead

Comment: @Justin - that's why you never pollute the global namespace. Create a single global namespace and attach everything that you need to be global to that namespace. e.g. `window['MYNAMESPACE'] = {}; window['MYNAMESPACE'].method = function() { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible keeping the actual function call in the HTML (on the a
>   tag) and have it work?

No. To use that method on the HTML element, `onclick=foo()`, then the function `foo` must be in the global scope.

Defining the function without the `var` keyword would allow it to enter the global scope:

```
$(function() {
   foo = function() { console.log('bar'); }
});
```

But it's never good to pollute the global scope, so why not namespace it?

```
$(function() {
   var ns = 'MYNAMESPACE';
   window[ns] = window[ns] || {}; //create a global namespace
   window[ns].foo = function() { console.log('bar'); }
});

<a href="#" onclick="MYNAMESPACE.foo()">Call foo</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible keeping the actual function call in the HTML (on the a
>   tag) and have it work?

No, if your function `foo` is not in the global scope or on one of a few special global objects then the HTML cannot find your function and there is nothing you can do in the HTML to change that.  For reference, your function `foo` is in a local scope, not in the global scope.  So, for the HTML to remain unchanged, you would have to move `foo` to the global scope or to one of a few global objects.

There are a bunch of reasons why it is not a great practice to embed function calls directly in the HTML.  One main reason is that it requires that those functions be globally scoped which, in itself, is not a good practice.

Since you already are using jQuery, you could simply change your code to this:

```
$(function() {
    function foo() {
        console.log("bar");
    }

    $("#callme").click(foo);
}

<a id="callme">Call foo</a>
```

Or, if you have multiple `<a>` tags that want the same click behavior, you can do this:

```
$(function() {
    function foo() {
        console.log("bar");
    }

    $(".callme").click(foo);
}

<a class="callme">Call foo</a>
<a class="callme">Call foo</a>
```

Or, either of these constructs could use an anonymous function:

```
$(function() {
    $(".callme").click(function(e) {
        console.log("bar");
    });
}

<a class="callme">Call foo</a>
<a class="callme">Call foo</a>
```

---

Removing all code references from the actual HTML is referred to as **Unobstrusive Javascript** and is considered a good practice by many.  You can read about that practice here:

[What is Unobtrusive JavaScript and Why it’s Important?](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/unobtrusive-javascript-important)

[Wikipedia - Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

[W3 - The principles of unobtrusive JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: `$("#callme").maybe()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
window.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log(e)
}

$(function() {

  function foo() {
    console.log("bar");
  }

  (function _foo() {
    return $(this).queue("foo", [function(next) {
      foo(); return next()}, _foo])
  }).call(this);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="jQuery(document).dequeue('foo')">Call foo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of [event handler content attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes) is

- The global scope
- The document
- The [form owner](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-owner) (if any)
- The element (if any)

That means that the `foo` function must be a property of one of those in order to use

```html
<a onclick="foo()">Call foo</a>
```

Some examples:

```js
(function() {
  window.foo = function() {
    alert("bar");
  }
})();
```

```html
<a onclick="foo()">Call foo</a>
```

```js
(function() {
  document.foo = function() {
    alert("bar");
  }
})();
```

```html
<a onclick="foo()">Call foo</a>
```

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelector('form').foo = function() {
    alert("bar");
  }
})();
```

```html
<form>
  <button onclick="foo()">Call foo</button>
</form>
```

```js
(function() {
  Element.prototype.foo = function() {
    alert("bar");
  }
})();
```

```html
<a onclick="foo()">Call foo</a>
```

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelector('a').foo = function() {
    alert("bar");
  }
})();
```

```html
<a onclick="foo()">Call foo</a>
```

However, I would suggest using [event handlers IDL attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes) or, even better, [event listeners](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener).